# Java socket setSoTimeout and performance hit

Tags: java, sockets, server

I'd like to gracefully close the serversocket. I have so far this code:

```html
    @Override
    public void init() throws IOException {


        listener = new ServerSocket();
        listener.setSoTimeout(1);
        listener.setReuseAddress(true);
        listener.bind(new InetSocketAddress(85));
        clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

        while (!clientProcessingPool.isShutdown()) {
            try {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                clientProcessingPool.submit(new StlExecutor(socket, this));
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        listener.close();
    }


    public void stop() throws Exception {
        clientProcessingPool.shutdownNow();
    }
```

Is it reasonable to set so low SO_TIMEOUT? What is reasonable value then? What is the performance hit?

Comment: `setSoTimeout()` will affect all of your blocking operations - including reads and writes.   If you are really legitimately worried about the amount of time it will take to `close()` the socket affecting performance, you'd best be using nonblocking I/O.

Comment: Unfortunatelly we are using JDK1.6

Comment: I'm concerned about the time it takes to shut down. The "reaction" time after it it shut down the server. Of course NIO will be better. Actually the reason I'm struggling with this is unit test. I need to stop, start server multiple times.

Comment: Setting SO_TIMEOUT isn't going to shut the socket down any faster - it's just going to detach the closing thread from the operation (the old IO interface does not throw SocketTimeoutException on `close()` for reasons that no one knows or cares about....)   If your processes execute in a serialized fashion, that won't be a problem, but it also won't save you any time.

Comment: Simply put, kill the server thread as fast as possible. I'm concerned about staying in accept only for 1 millisecond. Maybe I should make it property and for testing purposes set it to 1 and in production to 0(infinite)

Comment: SO_TIMEOUT will not make the server socket `close()` any faster, under any circumstances.   It may make the Java function /return/ faster - ie. before it actually closes (would have to check the JDK source), but it certainly can't make it close faster.

Comment: I need to kill the thread, the socket can be used again by  listener.setReuseAddress(true);